# OLAP/Datamart How to get started pushing data off of my database to a reporting database

Tags: sql, olap, datamart, data-cube

I work for a company We have many customers all hosted on one Database and one Schema.  All the customers need to be able to see their own data, but currently im using permissions and views joined to force them to their own data only based on data hierarchy.

This makes their reporting queries pretty exhaustive for the database.

I am starting to hear OLAP Cubes and Data-Mart would be useful to solve the problem.

Each Customers data points up to a Company Table

What would be the best way to offload this data somewhere where the customer could access their data semi real time while still keeping the workload off of my database server?

What do i search for with OLAP and Data-Mart to solve this problem?  Does anyone have any guides to show me step 1-10.

I was looking at this example but i don't understand Dimensions or Measure Groups.
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143031/building-your-first-data-cube/

Thanks

Comment: What kinds of queries are they running?  What's the layout of the database?  What are some of the views?  How many rows/tables do you have?  What sort of hardware?  What kind of information do they want to retrieve?  If you don't want this running on your 'database server', it's going to have to go on another machine - which may mean transferring files to your customers.  OLAP and Datamarts _do_ have some specialized hardware, but it's really more about architectural style... which is going to depend on what you're trying to do.  We need a heck of a lot more information.

Comment: Have look at [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com), e.g. online demo [here](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/). You can see what are dimensions and what are measures. In database, you can create one separate schema for each company (a.k.a. [datamart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart)). This will reduce (I guess) the query time. Data in database are mapped to (R)OLAP cube using OLAP schema, documentation for example for Mondrian is [here](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#What_is_a_schema)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an OLAP server (e.g., [icCube](http://www.icCube.com)). You might need to setup a separate DB server but this is not required as icCube is an in-memory OLAP server; once the cubes have been created there is no more access to the underlying DB.